# Armazenar lista em ViewState

Tags: c#, asp.net

Quero montar uma lista de strings e salvar em um viewstate, e usar depois.
Ex

```
List<string> listaNomes = new List<string>();
foreach(var algo in TesteList)
{
listaNomes.add(algo.id);
//salve essa lista em ViewState
}
```

Estou salvando varias strings nessa lista, porem preciso manipular o mesmo em outro local da pagina,como salvar em ViewState e manipular depois?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você quer usar em outra página essas informações você deve usar a sessão e não a viewState, a ViewState mantem as informações somente na página em que você está.

Use Session da seguinte forma.

Atribuindo a Lista a Sessão.

```
List<string> listaNomes = new List<string>();

    listaNomes.Add("Marconi");
    listaNomes.Add("Marcos");

    Session["Lista"] = listaNomes;
```

Recuperando a lista da Sessão em outra página ou na mesma página.

```
List<string> lista = (List<string>)Session["Lista"];
```

Se não precisar usar mais você pode remover o item da sessão.

```
Session.Remove("Lista");
```

Comment: deu certo vlw...